# Jmeter how do I get the right number for load?

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded a script against the application that I want to test.  Now, I am having a hard time arriving at the decision that what is that number that the application will run without any issue and to find out the max number of users.  Here is what I have done-

1. I have run the Jmeter script for 10, 50, 100, 150 users
2. Until 50 users, it runs like a charm. After about 80 users the throughput starts to come down and some samples do not show up in Aggregate Report.
3. I see heap memory problems in my console for about 150 users over period of time.  Is it the application problem or my machine problem?

Do you have an article where I could read about how to come to a conclusion about THE number?

UPDATE- after increasing the heap size, it is running smoothly for 100 users. I am even more confused now

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be anywhere!

**Server Performance Metrics collector:**

First you need an agent running in the application server to monitor the server performance while you are running the test.

This [link](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-server-performance-metrics-collector/) will give you an idea about the set up.

**JMeter Best Practices:**

I think that you are running your test in GUI mode with listeners. Most likely the problem is with your machine/your test. Ensure that you follow [this](https://blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure).

**Samples not showing in aggregate Report:**

You already asked a question on this in SO. Do not select 'Successes' in the Log/display only section of the listener while writing the results in the jtl. It will not write the failed requests details. You might need all the results. Once the jtl is created, you can always filter 'Success' only results as and when you want.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  For this 1st link of the server performance, after setting it up, what do I look for?  Do I look for 'the' number where my CPU utilization is 100%?  If so, is that my max number?

Comment: @arm, You can check both CPU and Memory utilization. Also check the application log if you think if it is application issue.